# Combine scalacheck Gen with Future In Scala

Tags: scala, monads, future, scalacheck, scala-cats

Basically I am trying to make generators which are the result of HTTP requests, due to this I often end up with types like `Gen[EitherT[Future, Error, T]]`.

The problem is that there doesn't appear to be any monadic instances (so I can do `sequence`, or monad transformers) that let me compose different instances of `Gen[EitherT[Future, Error, T]]`

As an example, suppose we have the following functions

`def genUser: Gen[EitherT[Future, Error, User]]`

and

`def genAccounts(user: User): Gen[EitherT[Future, Error, List[Account]]`

The idea is to be able to properly compose the `Gen[EitherT[Future, Error,T]` types, so that `genAccounts` calls `genUser`, i.e. something like

`def genAccounts(user: User): Gen[EitherT[Future, Error, List[Account]] = for {
   user <- genUser
   accounts <- genAccounts(user)
} yield accounts`

Also does scalacheck `Gen` provide a way to lift a `Future` into a `Gen` (i.e. a way to go from `Gen[Future[T]]` to just a `Gen[T]`). Even if this is blocking, its not a huge issue if it only happens once when we generate the final `Gen` property

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment (late 2022) there seems to be no native support on the ScalaCheck side for effectful generators. There was [one issue](https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck/issues/214) regarding asynchronous `Prop`s. As is mentioned in the issue, the solution is now implemented in the library [scalacheck-effect](https://github.com/typelevel/scalacheck-effect).

The above functionality could be a workaround, but would require nesting asynchronous properties rather than generating the data directly, e.g.

```scala
import org.scalacheck.Gen
import org.scalacheck.effect.PropF

import java.util.UUID
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{ Await, Future }

object TestAsync {

  case class Box(uuid: UUID)
  case class Wrapped(box: Box, name: Option[String])

  val propF: PropF[Future] = PropF.forAllF(Gen.uuid) { uuid =>
    Future(Box(uuid)).map { box =>
      PropF.forAllF(Gen.alphaNumStr) { name =>
        Future(Wrapped(box, Some(name))).map { wrapped =>
          PropF.boolean[Future](wrapped.name.nonEmpty)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Await.result(
      propF
        .check()
        .map(println),
      Duration.Inf
    )
  }

}
```

The use case is only for demonstration and already shows that using nested `PropF`s is somewhat involved.

Another option may be to use [ZIO](https://zio.dev/overview/), which handles values very similar to `EitherT[Future, Error, A]`, and has [effectful properties](https://zio.dev/reference/test/property-testing/).